# How do i sign .csr requests with CA root key

Tags: windows, powershell, tls1.2

I have created self-signed root certificate with PowerShell on my CA machine, and placed it in localmachine\my store.

Then client will need to send me a .csr request. How do I :

- create .csr on client?
- sign .csr on CA machine with my CA root private key?

This is what i used for creating CA root key pair:

```
$rootCAparams = @{
  DnsName = 'TestCA'
  KeyLength = 2048
  KeyAlgorithm = 'RSA'
  HashAlgorithm = 'SHA256'
  KeyExportPolicy = 'NonExportable'
  NotAfter = (Get-Date).AddYears(50)
  CertStoreLocation = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My'
  KeyUsage = 'CertSign','CRLSign' #fixes invalid certificate error
}

$rootCA = New-SelfSignedCertificate @rootCAparams
```

Comment: PowerShell is not CA software, there are no cmdlet's that ship with PowerShell (or Windows) that allow you to do that. You can use either `openssl` for windows, or (if you're on a newer version of Windows) the [`CertificateRequest` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I found that `certreq.exe -submit` will do the job. but how does it know that i want to sign with specific ROOT private key?

Comment: No, `certreq -submit` just submits the csr to an already running instance of Active Directory Certificate Services - so unless you've set up ADCS, that won't work